# Como fazer replace com valores nulos ou em branco

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**Problema:** Quando o cliente clica em enviar solicitação o sistema pega o produto selecionado e as dimensões daquele produto. Só que nem todos os produtos tem caixa ou seja qualquer outra característica do mesmo.

**Processo:** Quando o cliente clica em enviar orçamento um e-mail é disparado para a loja com o produto + dimensões (Tamanho, Caixa, Cor...)
Através do back-end eu dou um replace em meu Html por exemplo:

**Clase Enviar e-mail:**

```
 private string CorpoEmailOrcamento(string lead, string telefone, string email, string produto, string caixa, string essencia, string tamanho, string tipo, string utilizacao, string mensagem, string callback, string webRootPath)
    {

        string body = string.Empty;

        //using streamreader for reading my htmltemplate   

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(webRootPath, "emailmodel/orcamento.html")))
        {

            body = reader.ReadToEnd();

        }

        body = body.Replace("{lead}", lead);
        body = body.Replace("{telefone}", telefone);
        body = body.Replace("{email}", email);
        body = body.Replace("{produto}", produto);
        body = body.Replace("{<li><strong>Caixa:</strong> {caixa}</li>}", caixa);
        body = body.Replace("{essencia}", essencia);
        body = body.Replace("{tamanho}", tamanho);
        body = body.Replace("{tipo}", tipo);
        body = body.Replace("{utilizacao}", utilizacao);
        body = body.Replace("{mensagem}", mensagem);
        body = body.Replace("{callback}", callback);


        return body;

    }
```

Ai ele dá um replace nesse pedaço do código.

```
<ul>                                                                                                   
<li><strong>Nome:</strong> {lead}</li>                                                                                  <li><strong>Telefone:</strong> {telefone}</li>                                                                                                       <li><strong>Produto:</strong> {produto}</li>
<li><strong>Caixa:</strong> {caixa}</li>
<li><strong>Essência:</strong> {essencia}</li>
<li><strong>Tamanho:</strong> {tamanho}</li>
<li><strong>Tipo:</strong> {tipo}</li>
<li><strong>Utilização:</strong> {utilizacao}</li>
<li><strong>Mensagem:</strong> {mensagem}</li>
</ul>
```

Se o produto tiver alguma caracterista beleza ele envia certinho o problema esta sendo se o produto não tiver nenhuma caracteristica ai fica um resultado estranha no e-mial como por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Solução:** Gostaria de quando for enviado o email se o produto selecionado não tiver nenhuma caracteristica ai ele não exibe aquela configuração.

Exemplo se o Produto A não tiver caixa ele não precisa ir no Email Caixa: {caixa}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer a validação diretamente no C#, mas neste caso, o controle do HTML ficaria no server.

Exemplo
No server, ficaria a parte de validação e faz a inserção do conteúdo **HTML** ou de um **vazio**, caso a variável não tenha valor.

```
body = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lead) ? body.Replace("{lead}", string.Format("<li><strong>Nome: </strong>{0}</li>", lead)) : body.Replace("{lead}", "");
```

Na view, ficaria somente a tag `{lead}`, local onde o HTML será substituido pelo conteudo gerado no server.

Comment: Deu certinho muito obrigado.